# GPU-Passthrough from scratch / Shared GPU w/ Looking-Glass library

Tags: amd-graphics, kvm-virtualization, qemu, mesa, sound-blaster

I have installed an ubuntu 18.04.2 on a new system.
My hardware specs are as following:
2 x xeon 2670v1 
128gb ddr3 ecc
sapphire radeon r9 380
samsung evo 750 256gb

My objective is to run a Windows 10 machine (for games mostly) with kvm/qemu and gpu passthrough.
I am not sure how to approach this so my questions are:

-What gpu drivers would suit me best for passthrough? I have learned that there are some such as amdgpu-pro, mesa, etc. I don't plan on gaming on the barebone ubuntu.
-I also have a sound card (creative sound blaster z); are there any tools or drivers that can control the sound from this card?

I'm sorry, I'm new to linux and don't know what to do :)

Comment: The graphics drivers that best suit the system are the same ones for the use you want :) I mean, there are no special drivers for PCI passthrought,

Comment: How many graphics cards do you have? You need two, at least.

Comment: I have learned that there is a linux library for sharing video buffer between the host and the vm.

Comment: https://looking-glass.hostfission.com/

Comment: And to add to @GabrielaGarcia's point, you'll have better luck having graphics cards that are not made by the same company (ie: 1 AMD and 1 Nvidia vs 2 AMD cards) (and if it isn't obvious, a monitor per card).  You'll ensure Linux doesn't activate one, potentially mess with some BIOS settings, and allow the VM to turn it on without your actual system touching it.  It's not very simple but that shouldn't stop you from trying, just evaluate the level of effort vs trying to use the DX11 patches w. Vulkan in Wine :D

Comment: I have a dedicated gpu and an onboard gpu. But since its a desktop/workstation I can only use one at time.

Comment: You really need 2. The host OS cannot go without. Looking Glass - new to me - doesn't change that.

Comment: thanks Gabriela! appreciate your input. For me whats bugging me is how do I physically connect my display to my gpus.. one onboard with vga and one with mini-displayport..

Comment: @AlexandruHera I think you have a resonable question, but your title doesn't accurately reflect your issue.  Your title is more of a symptom.  Please consider re-wording your title to something that more accurately reflects "Unable to use GPU passthrough after installing Ubuntu", etc, unless you'll accept "You need two graphics cards and two monitors, so you can't", because that's the answer to the title you have right now.

Comment: @earthmeLon My point was to document before doing anything further. I found various guides online, but they all lack the same judgement, like starting from scratch, identifying hardware and best drivers/software depending on platform/cpu. I will change the title, and yes, looking glass looks promising although I'm not yet sure how it works.

Comment: Adding this here for anyone looking into looking-glass https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U44lihtNVVM